# MySql - How to insert and on duplicate key update without explicitly specifying all non key columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table which was created as a select * from a view (and then added a PK).

I want to periodically update the table with all the data from the view.

I thought the best option is to do this using: `INSERT INTO table_a SELECT * FROM view_a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` VALUES(non_key_col_1), VALUES(non_key_col_1), .... ;

Since there are quite a lot of columns, and they might change in the future (then I can re-create the table, but I wish I won't have to edit the periodic insert, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the explicit specification of all columns?

Comment: You are saying that the columns can also change in your view then I guess the best option would be to drop the table every time and recreate it from the view. The best option in your case would be a marialized view but those are not supported in mysql.

Comment: Impressive Ankur. Every word in that sentence was wrong. C: Luke Skywalker.

Comment: I ended up implementing a daily task  dropping and recreating the table automatically once a day. Something like this: 

"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `materialized_view_old`"
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `materialized_view_temp`"

"CREATE TABLE `materialized_view_temp` AS SELECT * FROM `my_view`"
"ALTER TABLE `materialized_view_temp` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD INDEX `ANOTHER_IDX` (`another_id` ASC)"
"RENAME TABLE `materialized_view` TO `materialized_view_old`, `materialized_view_temp` TO `materialized_view`"
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `materialized_view_old`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no such syntax in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) unfortunately. You'll have to update all the columns one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a trigger on insert operation, that is if the primary key exists update the row otherwise insert it. But definitely it is going to impact the performance in case of large data

Answer (score 0):

One thing i can think of is get the column names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and use those to dynamically compose your query in your app.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'view_a';
```

Now you have  the columns no matter if the view changes.

Do the same for the table and you have the column differences.
Use those differences to run ALTER TABLE statements or drop it and recreate it all together.

Of course this is probably even more laborious then dropping and recreating the table manually.